# I cannot get parallel computing working in Python (joblib)

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, joblib

import time
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

```
def fun(i):
    return i**2


start = time.time()
for i in list(range(0,10000000,1)):
    print(fun(i))
end = time.time()
print(end - start)



start = time.time()

Parallel(n_jobs=48,prefer="threads")(delayed(fun)(i) for i in list(range(0,10000000,1)))  
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

I am trying to use joblib to perform some computations in parallel. The 1st part of the code which is a traditional non-parallel for loop takes 37 seconds. The parallelized version runs for 6+ minutes without any ouput. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: something tells me you didn't read anything about python [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Comment: Mutlithreading does not magically improve the performance of your code, it comes at a cost. The operation you are trying to parallelise, `i**2`, is very, *very* fast, hence you are just going to pay the overhead of multithreading here. **You should provide your real use-case.**

Comment: Yes i**2 is just an example